# ftp Put *.ext only transfers the first file

Tags: ftp, wildcard, put

So I have a batch file which pipes some ftp commands into a host and I want to copy every file from my local directory with a certain extension to the host machine.

All that happens after i ftp is a directory change then

put *.ext
quit

It will put the first instance of any given file that it finds on the host but ignore all subsequent instances.  Anyone know why?

Comment: also for some reason this rendered the 'quit' on the same line as the put *.ext, it obviously isnt :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nevermind, I found out that 'put' will only process a single file.  The command I was looking for was 'mput'!